# PairedTTest - how to extract 95% confidence intervals for difference between paired means?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

```
data1 = {19.4, 21.2, 17.1, 21.1, 19.1, 18.2, 19.6};
data2 = {19.6, 21.1, 18.2, 21.8, 19.5, 18.3, 19.1};
PairedTTest[{data1, data2}]
```

How do I extract the 95% confidence intervals for the difference between the means from the PairedTTest?

Comment: `2 StandardDeviation[data2 - data1]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is surprising that such a common task is not available in the latest Statistics framework. `PairedTTest[{data1,data2},"ConfidenceInterval"]` really ought to return what you're after (i.e. the object from `PairedTTest[{data1,data2},0,"HypothesisTestData"]` ought to contain `"ConfidenceInterval"` as a property).

Confidence Intervals existed in V 5.2's package `` "Statistics`ConfidenceIntervals`" `` which was upgraded to the package `` HypothesisTesting` ``. This, in turn, was superseded by the new (kernel) framework of which `PairedTTest` is a member. To generate such a confidence interval then, go back to `` HypothesisTesting` ``.

```
Needs["HypothesisTesting`"]
data1 = {19.4, 21.2, 17.1, 21.1, 19.1, 18.2, 19.6};
data2 = {19.6, 21.1, 18.2, 21.8, 19.5, 18.3, 19.1};
MeanCI[data1 - data2]

(* {-0.757051, 0.214194} *)
```

`MeanCI`'s default assumptions match that for a `PairedTTest` confidence interval. To explicitly apply a "T-test confidence interval" the package's `StudentTCI` can instead be used to define "My" expected syntax:

```
MyPairedTTest[{data1_, data2_}, 0, "ConfidenceInterval"] := Let[
diff = data1 - data2,
n = Length@diff,
m = Mean@diff,
se = StandardDeviation@diff/Sqrt@n,

StudentTCI[m, se, n - 1]]

(* {-0.757051, 0.214194} *)
```

N.b, the package's `MeanDifferenceCI` will not do here since one of its assumptions is that both samples are *independent* (unlike the paired or matched case where individual effects are accounted for meaning that smaller differences can define significance; or equivalently,  matched-pairs' confidence intervals are tighter)

```
 MeanDifferenceCI[data1, data2]

 (* {-1.91857, 1.37571} *)
```

Comment: I didn't realise this package existed. It is very odd that WRI did not encapsulate this package in the [`HypothesisTestData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypothesisTestData.html) object. Some CI require a bit of extra calculation and/or contain several methods (e.g. rank correlation statistics) but that should not be an issue for *Mma*.

Comment: Yes, there are several puzzling things indicated with this omission. The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/HypothesisTesting.html) suggests it was the last item on a to-do list that never got completed. That such a query arises after such a long time (the framework was introduced in 2010) confirms something I've long suspected - there is a significant mismatch between the level of built-in statistical functionality and actual, or at least potential usage. I thought the 2010 framework really was an advance ...

Comment: ... in introducing a higher-level abstraction, systematization and subsequent automation  but one that doesn't seem to have caught on - I suspect because with such automation, adjuncts to black-box invocations become even more important something that I think will become especially relevant to the newer ML framework.

Comment: Use `data1={100}; data2={110};`. I cannot reproduce your results with the simple data in Mathematica 11.

Comment: @Masi Tests with sample sizes of 1 aren't really going to reveal too much so yes, the wasn't factored into the answer. All the reason why it would be nice to have a built-in version with all the i's crossed and t's dotted. I'm sure the answer can be modified until such time.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you can.  While I like the options with `LinearModelFit` and `NonlinearModelFit`, whoever wrote `PairedTTest` and `TTest` (and a few others) seemed to think that all one needs are *P*-values.

Here's how to get the confidence intervals in a brute-force way:

```
data1 = {19.4, 21.2, 17.1, 21.1, 19.1, 18.2, 19.6};
data2 = {19.6, 21.1, 18.2, 21.8, 19.5, 18.3, 19.1};

confidenceLevel = 0.95;
diff = data1 - data2;
n = Length[diff];
meanDiff = Mean[diff]
(* -0.271429 *)
se = StandardDeviation[diff]/Sqrt[n];
t = InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[n - 1], 1 - (1 - confidenceLevel)/2];
{lower, upper} = meanDiff + {-1, 1} t se
(* {-0.757051, 0.214194} *)
```